# How can make python read a csv file and list all of its components?

Tags: python, csv

Using Python, I defined a function that reads and prints a .csv file in the following way:

```
file_name= ('')
import sys

def get_lines(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    return lines

print (get_lines(file_name))
```

However, I don't know how to code the function in a way that lists the first 3 things of the first column and then lists all the two columns of the file next to each other, for example in the following way:

```
[Product1, Product2, Product3]
Product1   34
Product2   37
Product3   21

etc.
```

Comment: Python has a CSV module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This answer to a similar question lists some existing libraries that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937531/12679077

1. Tabulate: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate
2. PrettyTable: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable
3. texttable: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable
4. termtables: https://github.com/nschloe/termtables